# Insert a variable into a string

Tags: python, string

I have a simple multi-line string:

```
import wikipedia

html_str = """
<div class=c-box>
         <img display="none" class=cimg src="http://example.com">
             <h3>Example Information</h3>
              <div class=c-boxcontent>
                <p>

Variable Here
"""+var = wikipedia.summary("Julius Caesar", sentences=2) +"""

                </p>
              </div>
</div>
"""
```

How do I add a variable inside the `.c-box` so that it will be part of the HTML? Or is how I did the code right?

Comment: If you are going to extensively work with HTML, I would suggest you to try a [template engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating). I like [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Comment: @iluengo Thanks I am, but I was working on making my own (for simple uses :D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating large strings with `+` is kind of ugly in my opinion.  You should only use `+` when you have a few small strings to concatenate.

A cleaner approach would be to use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the value into the string:

```
html_str = """
<div class=c-box>
         <img display="none" class=cimg src="http://example.com">
             <h3>Example Information</h3>
              <div class=c-boxcontent>
                <p>

{}

                </p>
              </div>
</div>
""".format(wikipedia.summary("Julius Caesar", sentences=2))
```

Note too that your posted code is actually invalid since [assignment is a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt) in Python.  Meaning, you cannot perform an assignment in the middle of a line.

Comment: Weird? I tried thisimport wikipedia
`html_str = """
<div class=c-box>
         <img display="none" class=cimg src="http://example.com">
             <h3>Example Information</h3>
              <div class=c-boxcontent>
                <p>

{}

                </p>
              </div>
</div>
""".format(wikipedia.summary("Julius Caesar", sentences=2))`             With no luck, gave me this error :                        UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 39-40: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That is a separate issue being raised by the `wikipedia.summary` function.  I am not familiar with this function, so I cannot really help there.  You should ask a new question about the issue and include the traceback in the post.  You'll get the best help that way.